# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when publishing a message with RabbitTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I try to publish a message on a Queue with RabbitTemplate (using Spring Boot) and I got this message. I already tried to search for a solution.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads, received: com.example.demo.SimpleMessage
```

Maybe this part of code can help

```
@Override
    public void run(String...strings) throws Exception {

        SimpleMessage simpleMessage = new SimpleMessage();
        simpleMessage.setName("FirstMessage");
        simpleMessage.setDescription("simpleDescription");

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("TestExchange", "testRouting", simpleMessage);
    }
```

I appreciate any collaboration.

Comment: somewhere `SimpleMessageConverter.createMessage` is being called. I can't remember if convertAndSend calls that for you or not.

Comment: Looking at the source for spring, convertAndSend, calls `MessageConverter.toMessage` which calls `MessageConverter.createMessage` and since this is an instance of `SimpleMessage` we get `SimpleMessageConverter.createMessage`.

Comment: Agree with what Dylan has mentioned below. You need to make your object as Serializable. Take a look at some samples on sending message similar to your use case here. https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2016/10/23/produce-and-consume-json-messages-with-spring-boot-amqp/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that your class `SimpleMessage` does not implement `Serializable`.

`RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` uses `SimpleMessageConveter` to convert your message into an amqp message. However `SimpleMessageConverter` requires that message to implement the interface `Serializable`.

Your `SimpleMessage` class should look like follows:

```
public class SimpleMessage implements Serializable {
    ... your code here
}
```

You can learn more about Serializable objects [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).

Answer (score 6):

There is another solution: use a different implementation of the MessageConverter instead of default SimpleMessageConverter.

For example, Jackson2JsonMessageConverter:

```
public RabbitTemplate jsonRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    final var jsonRabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    jsonRabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper));
    return jsonRabbitTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing rabbitTemplate helped. First I had this one:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
}
```

And then I've changed it to this one:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter(ObjectMapper jsonMapper) {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(jsonMapper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the object that you are trying to convert and send it via `convertAndSend()` method provided by rabbitTemplate, so in my example is like so:

```
"rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("", "user-registration", userRegistrationRequest);"
```

here I am trying to convert and pass `UserRegistrationRequest` object, the object`UserRegistrationRequest` used on the method does not implement the Serializable interface, so only by implementing the Serializable interface, the error was vanished.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion @Yunnosch, of course i will check out this and i will try to make my answers more clear in the future.

Comment: just did it, so let me know if something still missing. Thanks a lot!